# MacOS android studio NDK was located by using ndk.dir property. This method is deprecated

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am getting the following warming messages:

> WARNING:: NDK was located by using ndk.dir property. This method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please delete ndk.dir from local.properties and set android.ndkVersion to [21.4.7075529] in all native modules in the project. https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/ndk-dir

> NDK was located by using ndk.dir property. This method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please delete ndk.dir from local.properties and set android.ndkVersion to [21.4.7075529] in all native modules in the project. https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/ndk-dir

At the moment I am using the local.properties file like this:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/nameUser/Library/Android/sdk
ndk.dir=/Users/nameUser/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529
```

I need to put this in the `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion -> 21.4.7075529
     ...
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's more like an answer I guess. I installed that specific version https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#specific-version and the warning is gone.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it by following these steps.

1. In **local.properties**, remove this line:

   ```
   ndk.dir=/Users/nameUser/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529
   ```
2. In **app/build.gradle**, replace this line:

   ```
   ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
   ```

   with:

   ```
   android.ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
   ```
3. Sync gradle